# Time synchronization

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, time, timer

I am creating a web application in Java in which I need to run a reverse timer on client browser. I have planned to send the remaining time from server to client and then tick the timer using javascript.
My questions are:
1. Does the clock tick rate varies with different systems?
2. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *Does the clock tick rate varies with different systems?*

Yes, it's the result of really, really small differences of frequencies of the quatrz used in chipsets. So if you do not synchronize your clocks now and then, they will diverge.

However, if you're not designing a satellite, remote control for ballistic missiles, or life supporting devices, you really should not care.

#### *Is there any better way to do this?*

Yes, if:

- your reverse clock counts down from a year or *at least* month, or
- you are running your client on a device with broken / really inaccurate clock

you may use a `NTP protocol` to make sure the client and the server clocks are synchronized. There are NTP libraries available for [JavaScript](http://jehiah.cz/a/ntp-for-javascript) and [Java](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient).

Answer (score 0):

@npe -s solution with NTP will do, but is theoretically incorrect:

Even if the clocks are perfectly sync-ed, you will send the client the **remaining-time**. But that message needs to travel on the net, so by the time the client receives it it won't be correct anymore.

A better approach would be to send the **end time** to the client, which is an absolute value, hence not affected by network lag and do the countdown on the client, calculating the remaining-time there.

*that said, the other answers about NTP are also necessary of course*